# OnClick UI Button Grow Effect Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-engine

How to do this in unity3D game engine ? When Click on UI button then UI button Has Grow Effect ?

Do i need a particle system ? I don't know how to make a particle system with grow effect. Or if no need particle system so how to make it ? Using a material ?

Is there any tutorial or reference site youtube or any site i can find this tutorial ? If not, how is the step to do this ?

Example :

Please See the Screenshot below. Button Before click and After clicked.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Look like i find the better solution about this effect at a button grow.

In this case we must use a shader.

Read this link about shader : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Shaders.html

Also this how to make it :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMLbbi8oaO8

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for one button type  may be create sprite with grow and change alpha for his texture when button pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in Button Inspector follow Transition: SpriteSwap

```
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-SelectableTransition.html
```